# Debug ata error messages?

Tags: centos, sata

my Centos 6 server has been playing recently in that it seems to freeze up and lose network access. I've been getting a load of `ata5` error messages in the log and after some digging have determined that the drive is sda, the root filesystem.

Another post with similar issues suggested changing the SATA cable, which i've done but the errors still persist.

I've also set `fsck` to run at each boot up (as it's the root filesystem) although i'm not sure it's running as there's nothing appearing on screen during boot to suggest it's running (should there be?). I basically set the `maximum mount count` to 1 with `tune2fs`.

Sometimes the system works fine, but i went away for a couple of days over the weekend and it was dead on my return. A simple hard reset brought it back again, but obviously I need to get to the bottom of it.

```
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata7: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata7.00: ATA-7: SAMSUNG HD103UJ, 1AA01113, max UDMA7
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata7.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: ATA-8: SanDisk SDSSDX120GG25, R211, max UDMA/133
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: 234441648 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata7.00: configured for UDMA/133
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      SanDisk SDSSDX12 R211 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata6: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata6.00: ATA-8: ST31000524AS, JC4B, max UDMA/133
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata6.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST31000524AS     JC4B PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      SAMSUNG HD103UJ  1AA0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata8: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata8.00: HPA detected: current 1953523055, native 1953525168
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata8.00: ATA-8: WDC WD10EARX-00N0YB0, 51.0AB51, max UDMA/133
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata8.00: 1953523055 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata8.00: configured for UDMA/133
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD10EARX-00N 51.0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [AXV8] enabled at IRQ 16
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ahci 0000:04:00.0: PCI INT A -> Link[AXV8] -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ahci 0000:04:00.0: AHCI 0001.0000 32 slots 2 ports 3 Gbps 0x3 impl SATA mode
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ahci 0000:04:00.0: flags: 64bit ncq led clo pmp pio 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: scsi8 : ahci
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: scsi9 : ahci
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata9: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xdfcfe000 port 0xdfcfe100 irq 16
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata10: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xdfcfe000 port 0xdfcfe180 irq 16
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata9: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata10: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: pata_jmicron 0000:04:00.1: PCI INT B -> Link[AXV5] -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: scsi10 : pata_jmicron
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: scsi11 : pata_jmicron
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata11: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0x8c00 ctl 0x8800 bmdma 0x7c00 irq 16
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata12: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0x8400 ctl 0x8000 bmdma 0x7c08 irq 16
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [APC4] enabled at IRQ 19
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: firewire_ohci 0000:03:07.0: PCI INT A -> Link[APC4] -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: firewire_ohci: Added fw-ohci device 0000:03:07.0, OHCI version 1.10
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: STARTING CRC_T10DIF
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] 234441648 512-byte logical blocks: (120 GB/111 GiB)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sdb:
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sdc:
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sda:
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] 1953523055 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sdd: sda1 sda2
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sdc1
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sdd1
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sdb1
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: dracut: Scanning devices sda2  for LVM logical volumes vg_centos/lv_swap vg_centos/lv_root 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: dracut: inactive '/dev/vg_centos/lv_root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: dracut: inactive '/dev/vg_centos/lv_home' [57.48 GiB] inherit
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: dracut: inactive '/dev/vg_centos/lv_swap' [3.81 GiB] inherit
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: dracut: Mounted root filesystem /dev/mapper/vg_centos-lv_root
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: SELinux:  Disabled at runtime.
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: firewire_core: created device fw0: GUID 56a213d400044b18, S400
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: type=1404 audit(1432645472.858:2): selinux=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: dracut: 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: dracut: Switching root
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: EH in SWNCQ mode,QC:qc_active 0x60000007 sactive 0x60000007
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: SWNCQ:qc_active 0x60000001 defer_bits 0x6 last_issue_tag 0x0
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel:  dhfis 0x60000001 dmafis 0x60000001 sdbfis 0x0
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: ATA_REG 0x40 ERR_REG 0x0
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: tag : dhfis dmafis sdbfis sacitve
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: tag 0x0: 1 1 0 1  
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: tag 0x1d: 1 1 0 1  
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: tag 0x1e: 1 1 0 1  
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x60000007 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/90:00:c8:91:59/00:00:05:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 73728 in
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel:         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/08:08:08:b5:0f/00:00:04:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 4096 in
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel:         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/78:10:90:b5:0f/00:00:04:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 61440 in
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel:         res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/08:e8:00:b5:0f/00:00:04:00:00/40 tag 29 ncq 4096 in
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel:         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/80:f0:10:b5:0f/00:00:04:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq 65536 in
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel:         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: hard resetting link
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: SRST failed (errno=-16)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: hard resetting link
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]  Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] [descriptor]
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel:        72 0b 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel:        00 00 00 00 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]  Add. Sense: No additional sense information
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 04 0f b5 90 00 00 78 00
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 68138384
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]  Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] [descriptor]
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel:        72 0b 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel:        00 00 00 00 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]  Add. Sense: No additional sense information
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 04 0f b5 00 00 00 08 00
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 68138240
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]  Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] [descriptor]
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel:        72 0b 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel:        00 00 00 00 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]  Add. Sense: No additional sense information
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 04 0f b5 10 00 00 80 00
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 68138256
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ata5: EH complete
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: udev: starting version 147
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [AAZA] enabled at IRQ 23
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0f.1: PCI INT B -> Link[AAZA] -> GSI 23 (level, low) -> IRQ 23
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: hda_intel: Disabling MSI
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: input: HDA NVidia Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.1/sound/card0/input6
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: input: HDA NVidia Line Out Side as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.1/sound/card0/input7
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: input: HDA NVidia Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.1/sound/card0/input8
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: input: HDA NVidia Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.1/sound/card0/input9
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: input: HDA NVidia Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.1/sound/card0/input10
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: input: HDA NVidia Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.1/sound/card0/input11
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: input: HDA NVidia Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.1/sound/card0/input12
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: input: HDA NVidia Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0f.1/sound/card0/input13
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: PCI INT B -> Link[AXV6] -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: hda-intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle VGA-switcheroo audio client
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input14
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: i2c i2c-0: nForce2 SMBus adapter at 0xf400
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: i2c i2c-1: nForce2 SMBus adapter at 0xf000
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: forcedeth: Reverse Engineered nForce ethernet driver. Version 0.64.
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [AMAC] enabled at IRQ 22
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: forcedeth 0000:00:11.0: PCI INT A -> Link[AMAC] -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: md: bind<sdb1>
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: forcedeth 0000:00:11.0: ifname eth0, PHY OUI 0x50ef @ 0, addr 00:04:4b:16:84:be
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: forcedeth 0000:00:11.0: highdma csum vlan pwrctl mgmt gbit lnktim msi desc-v3
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [AMA1] enabled at IRQ 23
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: forcedeth 0000:00:12.0: PCI INT A -> Link[AMA1] -> GSI 23 (level, low) -> IRQ 23
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: forcedeth 0000:00:12.0: ifname eth1, PHY OUI 0x50ef @ 1, addr 00:04:4b:16:84:bf
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: forcedeth 0000:00:12.0: highdma csum vlan pwrctl mgmt gbit lnktim msi desc-v3
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: md: bind<sdc1>
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: microcode: CPU0 sig=0x10677, pf=0x10, revision=0x703
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: platform microcode: firmware: requesting intel-ucode/06-17-07
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: microcode: CPU1 sig=0x10677, pf=0x10, revision=0x703
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: platform microcode: firmware: requesting intel-ucode/06-17-07
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: microcode: CPU2 sig=0x10677, pf=0x10, revision=0x703
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: platform microcode: firmware: requesting intel-ucode/06-17-07
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: md: raid1 personality registered for level 1
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: bio: create slab <bio-1> at 1
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: md/raid1:md127: active with 2 out of 2 mirrors
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: created bitmap (8 pages) for device md127
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: md127: bitmap initialized from disk: read 1 pages, set 0 of 14903 bits
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: microcode: CPU3 sig=0x10677, pf=0x10, revision=0x703
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: platform microcode: firmware: requesting intel-ucode/06-17-07
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: md127: detected capacity change from 0 to 1000068022272
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: md127: unknown partition table
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: microcode: CPU0 updated to revision 0x70a, date = 2010-09-29 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: microcode: CPU1 updated to revision 0x70a, date = 2010-09-29 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: microcode: CPU2 updated to revision 0x70a, date = 2010-09-29 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: microcode: CPU3 updated to revision 0x70a, date = 2010-09-29 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: EXT4-fs (sdd1): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: EXT4-fs (sdd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: EXT4-fs (md127): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: Adding 3997692k swap on /dev/mapper/vg_centos-lv_swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:3997692k SSD
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: NET: Registered protocol family 10
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: Bridge firewalling registered
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: eth1: no link during initialization.
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: device eth1 entered promiscuous mode
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: br0: port 1(eth0) entering forwarding state
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: eth1: link up.
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: br0: port 2(eth1) entering forwarding state
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: type=1305 audit(1432645521.660:3): audit_pid=1315 old=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: p4-clockmod: Warning: EST-capable CPU detected. The acpi-cpufreq module offers voltage scaling in addition to frequency scaling. You should use that instead of p4-clockmod, if possible.
May 26 14:05:22 centos rpc.statd[1411]: Version 1.2.3 starting
May 26 14:05:22 centos sm-notify[1412]: Version 1.2.3 starting
May 26 14:05:22 centos kdump: kexec: loaded kdump kernel
May 26 14:05:22 centos kdump: started up
May 26 14:05:22 centos acpid: starting up
May 26 14:05:22 centos acpid: 1 rule loaded
May 26 14:05:22 centos acpid: waiting for events: event logging is off
May 26 14:05:22 centos acpid: client connected from 1640[68:68]
May 26 14:05:22 centos acpid: 1 client rule loaded
May 26 14:05:22 centos kernel: w83627ehf: Found W83627DHG chip at 0x290
May 26 14:05:23 centos automount[1676]: lookup_read_master: lookup(nisplus): couldn't locate nis+ table auto.master
May 26 14:05:25 centos abrtd: Init complete, entering main loop
May 26 14:05:25 centos pptpd[2015]: MGR: connections limit (100) reached, extra IP addresses ignored
May 26 14:05:25 centos pptpd[2016]: MGR: Manager process started
May 26 14:05:25 centos pptpd[2016]: MGR: Maximum of 100 connections available
May 26 14:05:25 centos smbd[2043]: [2015/05/26 14:05:25.786741,  0] param/loadparm.c:7969(lp_do_parameter)
May 26 14:05:25 centos smbd[2043]:   Ignoring unknown parameter "symlinks"
May 26 14:05:34 centos kernel: br0: port 1(eth0) entering forwarding state
May 26 14:05:35 centos kernel: br0: port 2(eth1) entering forwarding state
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5: EH in SWNCQ mode,QC:qc_active 0xF sactive 0xF
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5: SWNCQ:qc_active 0x7 defer_bits 0x8 last_issue_tag 0x2
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel:  dhfis 0x7 dmafis 0x7 sdbfis 0x0
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5: ATA_REG 0x40 ERR_REG 0x0
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5: tag : dhfis dmafis sdbfis sacitve
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5: tag 0x0: 1 1 0 1  
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5: tag 0x1: 1 1 0 1  
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5: tag 0x2: 1 1 0 1  
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0xf SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/08:00:f8:bf:20/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq 4096 in
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel:         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/48:08:68:c0:20/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 1 ncq 36864 in
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel:         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/20:10:d8:c0:20/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq 147456 in
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel:         res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/08:18:78:cf:d0/00:00:03:00:00/40 tag 3 ncq 4096 in
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel:         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY }
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5: hard resetting link
May 26 14:06:02 centos kernel: ata5: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
May 26 14:06:08 centos kernel: ata5: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
May 26 14:06:12 centos kernel: ata5: SRST failed (errno=-16)
May 26 14:06:12 centos kernel: ata5: hard resetting link
May 26 14:06:12 centos kernel: ata5: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5: EH complete
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5: EH in SWNCQ mode,QC:qc_active 0xFF0 sactive 0xFF0
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5: SWNCQ:qc_active 0xF0 defer_bits 0xF00 last_issue_tag 0x7
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel:  dhfis 0xF0 dmafis 0xE0 sdbfis 0x0
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5: ATA_REG 0x41 ERR_REG 0x84
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5: tag : dhfis dmafis sdbfis sacitve
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5: tag 0x4: 1 0 0 1  
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5: tag 0x5: 1 1 0 1  
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5: tag 0x6: 1 1 0 1  
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5: tag 0x7: 1 1 0 1  
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0xff0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: Ata error. fis:0x21
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/08:20:78:cf:d0/00:00:03:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq 4096 in
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel:         res 41/84:38:f8:bf:20/84:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/20:28:d8:c0:20/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq 147456 in
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel:         res 41/84:38:f8:bf:20/84:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/48:30:68:c0:20/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 6 ncq 36864 in
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel:         res 41/84:38:f8:bf:20/84:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 60/08:38:f8:bf:20/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 7 ncq 4096 in
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel:         res 41/84:38:f8:bf:20/84:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 61/08:40:b0:ff:d3/00:00:03:00:00/40 tag 8 ncq 4096 out
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel:         res 41/84:38:f8:bf:20/84:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 61/08:48:90:ca:3b/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq 4096 out
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel:         res 41/84:38:f8:bf:20/84:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 61/08:50:08:e0:3f/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 10 ncq 4096 out
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel:         res 41/84:38:f8:bf:20/84:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: cmd 61/c8:58:48:b9:13/01:00:03:00:00/40 tag 11 ncq 233472 out
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel:         res 41/84:38:f8:bf:20/84:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5.00: error: { ICRC ABRT }
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5: hard resetting link
May 26 14:06:13 centos kernel: ata5: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
May 26 14:06:14 centos kernel: ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
May 26 14:06:14 centos kernel: ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
May 26 14:06:14 centos kernel: ata5: EH complete
```

Comment: Since you haven't posted the actual error messages, it's very difficult to debug them. However, `ata` error messages are often caused by hardware errors from the disk controller. I'd replace the hard disk and ensure that current data is securely backed up to avoid data loss.

Comment: Sorry! Was trying to work out how to upload and then got distracted. OK, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Hard disk errors

`ata` error messages are caused by hardware errors from the disk controller.  Errors such as the following are caused by failure to read correctly from the hard disk:

```
sd 4:0:0:0: [sda]  Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] [descriptor]
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel: Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
May 26 14:05:21 centos kernel:        72 0b 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00
```

Since you already replaced the SATA cable, we can rule that out as a cause.  The disk is failing and will need to be replaced. I’ve had such intermittent errors in the past only for the disk to eventually fail completely.  I’d replace the hard disk and in the mean time, ensure that current data is securely backed up to avoid data loss.

#### Filesystem check

Since the problems are at the disk level rather than the filesystem, running `fsck` won’t resolve the underlying issues. However, it should still be worth doing – to get information on (and to help maintain) the integrity of your filesystem.  You can enforce a file system check when starting by modifying the sixth field (`fs_passno`) in your `/etc/fstab`. Change the `fs_passno` from 0 to 1 for the root filesystem and to 2 for other filesystems (see `man fstab` for more details).

Comment: Thanks for that Anthony - that current disk is a 120GB SSD. I've only had it a couple of years, and as the server is running constantly, would you suggest replacing with the same, or a standard SATA drive?

Comment: @pavsid I’ve only ever used SATA (and IDE in olden times) drives and I’ve no experience of using SSD drives in a server but I’m not aware of any issues with using aside from the limited number of writes (which you possibly may have run into with your current drive).